# Use an iOS specific element in a Xamarin Forms app

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'd like to use an iOS specific element (SceneKitView) in my Xamarin Forms app but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/creating), but I'm not sure if I'll be able to create a visual element (aka a view) this way.

What classes should I implement and what configurations do I have to do to achieve this? Also, I'm using a different D.I. framework than the one provided by Xamarin, is that gonna be a problem (I'm using Ninject)?

Basically, my question is how do you create custom cross-platform views in Xamarin Forms (a github example would be great!).

*I know there is a cross-platform equivalent to SceneKit but right now I don't have the time to redo the code for the 3D scene.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it.

The concept is called Custom Renderers.

Here a link to the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/